# NTFS Error - file system structure is corrupt and unusable

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, event-log, volume-shadow-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [windows 7: Event 55 The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable](https://superuser.com/questions/359366/windows-7-event-55-the-file-system-structure-on-the-disk-is-corrupt-and-unusabl)

My Windows 7 (64-bit) keeps completely locking up, and I have to hold the power button to shut it down. Event logs are showing `EventID 55`. I realize that this can be a warning sign of an impending disk failure, but my data on this machine is safely backed up and I don't feel like taking the time to replace the drive right now.

When I have seen this problem before, I have been able to delete the offending folder with a Linux Live CD (when `CHKDSK /F` didn't work). In this case, the folder is from VSS. I assume this is from Crashplan, my online backup provider. What are the ramifications of deleting this folder from Linux? Is it safe to do?

*"The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy26."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's time to perform a disk diagnostic like Hitachi Drive Fitness Test (free) to diagnose if the disk is in fact, failing.  Otherwise you'll be on a wild goose chase.

Comment: I did try running Western Digital's Data Lifeguard tool. It detects bad sectors, and when I try to repair, I get the fantastic error message "Error detected while repairing bad sectors."

Comment: Bad sectors aren't something that can be "repaired"; they usually just get marked as unusable and it's up to the firmware to relocate them.